# como puedo realizar una consulta con solo el mes y la fecha en SQL

Tags: sql, base-de-datos, oracle

Como puedo hacer una consulta en la BD solo tomando el mes y el año de una fecha, estaba intentando esto pero marca que el mes no es valido

```
SELECT *
       FROM CL_RP_COBRANZA_TNR
       WHERE TO_DATE(FECHA_VENCIMIENTO,'MM/RRRR') = TO_DATE('10/2015','MM/RRRR');
```

Comment: ¿Y que problema has tenido con tu consulta?

Comment: me arroja el error que el mes no es valido, y no se realiza la consulta de forma correcta, nose si en algo esta mal, espero puedas ayudarme

Comment: ¿Que tipo de dato es  `FECHA_VENCIMIENTO`? ¿Podrías compartir algún ejemplo de los mismos?

Answer (score 0):

Esta es mi solución espero te funcione amigo:

```
SELECT * FROM CL_RP_COBRANZA_TNR 
WHERE YEAR(FECHA_VENCIMIENTO) = '2015' 
AND MONTH(FECHA_VENCIMIENTO) = '10'
```

Comment: ya lo intene a migo y me arroja error en month que no es valido, y se cambio el orden de los filtros ahora me arroja el year amigo que podra ser?

Comment: Revisa en que formato tienes tu campo, puede ser eso lo que esta afectándote debe estar en datetime o date me parece mas un error de sintaxis debería funcionar

Comment: es decir que le coloque una mascara ?, por que lo que e marca como error es el year o el month como no valido

Comment: ya encontre la solucion

Comment: select *
from cl_rp_cobranza_tnr
where to_char(fecha_vencimiento,'mm/rrrr') = '10/2015';

Comment: Que bueno amigo éxitos.

Answer (score 0):

esta es la respuesta de como poder realizar busquedas de acuerdo al mes y al año

```
select * from DUAL
where to_char(CAMPO,'mm/rrrr') = '10/2015';
```